# Measure performance for react router v4

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-router

I'm Using react-router v4

How can I effectively measure (via navigation timing  `performance.mark` and `performance.measure`) how long it takes for a user from the click event on the link until the updated / rendered route he navigated to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you defining your routes?

If you are utilizing `<Link/>` components, you could register your performance mark in an `onClick` handler as a side-effect. For example, something like the following:

```
<Link
    to="some/great/component"
    onClick={() => performance.mark('initialize_page_change')}
/>
```

Then, in the component that will render as a result of the route-change, you'll want to make a call to `performance.mark` again. You'll probably want to make use of React's [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) for this purpose. I'd recommend using the constructor function or `componentWillMount()`. In your component that corresponds to the above link:

```
componentWillMount() {
    performance.mark('target_page_mounted');
}
```

And finally, to measure your marks:

```
performance.measure('reactRouterPerf',
                    'initialize_page_change',
                    'target_page_mounted'
                   );
```

Comment: Cool! I am curios why you are recommending to do the second mark in   `componentWillMount`, Shouldn't rather be in the `render` method right before the `return` statement inside a `setTimeout, 0` so its gets much  closer to the real rendering time?

Comment: I assumed you wanted to measure perf of RR and not your own components. Take the case of a component that delays rendering, eg while awaiting an api call. If your component does some setup before rendering, your perf test would be conflating RR's perf and an inefficient component's perf. If you want to measure post-render, put the call in ```componentDidMount``` instead. Having the mark in render is problematic bc the render can be called every time your component updates, leading to many needless calls. Also, no need for setTimeout. Oh, and would greatly appreciate if you accept my answer!

Comment: Yea, I am calling a API and render handles initial state and after API returned.. I am not sure how do properly do it in `componentDidMount ` and only run after API has returned so it did render https://gist.github.com/adardesign/1f2695db8f8bbf4525d98ce342a61d65

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. Well ```componentDidMount``` will only be called after first render, at which point your API request will be processed. You could always put it in the promise chain of your api request after ```this.setState``` on line 13 (just copy the body of your setState callback there). That will ensure it will only drop the performance mark once your component has rendered and your data has returned